# Simple program not working

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

this is the first time i work on C# and ASP.NET, i'm reading Beginning ASP.NET 4 in c# 2010 but i never worked with object-oriented programming. (I'm a network admin so i know basic programming).

Still, i can't get to work a simple program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int i;
            string[] nomi = new string[7];
            string[] cognomi = new string[7];
            for (i = 0; i = 6; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il", i + 1, "° nome");
                nomi[i] = (Console.ReadLine);
            }

            for (i = 0; i = 6; i++) {

                Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il", i + 1, "° cognome");
                nomi[i] = (Console.ReadLine);
            }

            for (i = 0; i = 6; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(nomi[i], " ", cognomi[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem is not in the algorythm but in the declaration part. I can't show the error log because i have VS in Italian.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Change your `(Console.ReadLine);`s to `Console.ReadLine();`. As it is, you're trying to assign a function delegate (which is not a `string`) to a position in a `string` array. You want to actually get a string from the Console, so you need to *call* the function. After the change, the console should wait for you to type something and press enter before continuing on.

Comment: lol if that codes from book throw it garbage

Comment: **Notice:** You're writing to `nomi[i]` in your second loop when you mean to write to `cognomi[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tough to help without error messages (maybe you can translate them since you obviously know both languages).

For sure, your `for` loop syntax is incorrect. This:

```
for (i = 0; i = 6; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)  // Or <=, or whatever
```

Take a look at [for loop documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

In addition `Console.ReadLine` [is a method, not a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx):

```
nomi[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/s35hcfh7(v=vs.80).aspx

This is one of the errors

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loops are incorrect. They should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
}
```

Or, better,

```
for (int i = 0; i < nomi.Length; i++)
{
}
```

What this is saying is that `i` should start at `0`, continue looping until the value if `i` is no longer less than `7` (or the value of `nomi.Length`) and `i` should increase by 1 each loop (`i++`).

Also, unrelated to the loops, it should be `Console.ReadLine();`. The `()` shows that it's a method that takes no parameters, whereas `nomi.Length` does not have `()` because it is a `property`, not a `method`.

Your arrays also need to be static.

```
static string[] nomi = new string[7];
static string[] cognomi = new string[7];
```

Just to clarify, you don't always need to use `static` when declaring variables. The reason you need it here is because you're calling them from within a static method (`static void Main(string[] args)`).

Edit - As mentioned in the comments, this assumes that the variables are being declated outside the `Main` method which is resulting in the error `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'`. If they are not, then these variables do not have to be static.

Comment: You can't declare static variables inside of a method.

Comment: Yes, you're right there. However, based on OP's error message (`An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'`), I'm guessing they copy pasted the code wrong and actually declared those variables outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops don't make any sense `for (i = 0; i = 6; i++)`

The syntax is `for (initialization, condition, iteration)`

Right now your condition is an assignment, so it is always going to be true. I think you wanted it to be `for (i = 0; i **<** 6; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

When writing for loops you should always make a int variable in the scope of the declaration of the for loop

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    body code goes here
}
```

There integer should be declared and disappear within the scope of the loop.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your `for` and `Console.WriteLine` syntax  and made your code more readable. This should be able to guide you.

```
const int length = 7;
string[] nomi = new string[length];
string[] cognomi = new string[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il {0} ° nome", i + 1);
    nomi[i] = (Console.ReadLine());
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inserisci il {0} ° cognome", i + 1);
    cognomi[i] = (Console.ReadLine());
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("nomi: {0} cogomi: {1}", nomi[i], cognomi[i]);
}
```

Comment: The variable declarations needs to be static.

Comment: @keyboardP Why? They're stack variables inside of a method and you can't make stack variable static.

Comment: Because OP's error message implies that they're being declared outside the method (`An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'`). I'm guessing this means that code is incorrectly copied in the question but I may be missing something else.

Comment: Guys can you recommend me some resources to properly learn it? In that book there's just 1 chapter about it. Thanks

Comment: @WiFonzus Try using the code presented here to get your code working. It'll be a good learning step.

Comment: Yup, that worked but the program is only showing nomi[i] but not cognomi[i]. Thanks

Comment: @WiFonzus There's Pluralsight and Channel9 if you like videos. You could try this [Channel9 series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) to get you started.

Comment: @WiFonzus are you trying to print out both because your syntax for Console.WriteLine is wrong then, I will make an edit.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the trouble, but the only programming language i've used so far was Pascal (for three years!) in high school. (:

Comment: @WiFonzus It's no problem. `Console.WriteLine` expects a format string from which it can substitute values. For example, the formatter `{0}` will tell `Console.WriteLine` to substitute the first argument given, so `Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", "World")` will print `Hello World!`